How to Add a Newline to an Apple Notes Entry Using AppleScript
I'm trying to create a Bash script on macOS that appends the clipboard content to the top of an existing Apple Notes entry titled "Clipboard" while preserving newlines. The script uses pbpaste to get the clipboard content and osascript with AppleScript to insert this content into the note. However, I'm encountering issues where newlines are not being added in the note. I’ve attempted several methods to handle newline characters, including linefeed and return in AppleScript, as well as adding \n in Bash. Any advice on how to achieve this would be really appreciated.
I tried multiple ways to add newlines  to the Apple Notes entry. Initially, I used pbpaste in Bash to get the clipboard content and tried both & linefeed and  & return within AppleScript to add line breaks before and after the clipboard content, expecting the text to be formatted with a newline after the copied text. However, the note had all text in a single line, with newlines ignored.
Code:
#!/bin/bash

CLIPBOARD_CONTENT=$(pbpaste)
CLIPBOARD_CONTENT_ESCAPED=$(echo "$CLIPBOARD_CONTENT" | sed 's/"/\"/g')
/usr/bin/osascript <<EOD
tell application "Notes"
set theNote to first note whose name is "Clipboard"

set currentBody to body of theNote as text

set noteLines to paragraphs of currentBody

set noteTitle to item 1 of noteLines

set noteBody to (items 2 thru -1 of noteLines as text)

set newBody to noteTitle & linefeed & "$CLIPBOARD_CONTENT_ESCAPED" & linefeed & noteBody

set body of theNote to newBody

end tell
EOD
Output:
Clipboard
consideration
detected
dan


Please post code & results as text, not images of text.

The body of a note is the HTML content (which is kinda crappy, with just about everything in a division) - try plaintext.
